# Give all the nodes on a tree a positive number $v_i$ such that no adjacent nodes share the same number, what is the minimum $\sum v_i$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Suppose you have to give all the nodes on a tree a positive number $v_i$ such that no adjacent nodes share the same number, what is the minimum $\sum v_i$?

I came across this problem on a programming platform. I had solved it but I had a few doubts concerning it.

1. When I was solving this problem, I thought that $\max(v_i) = 3$ were always enough but apparently there were some cases where $\max(v_i)$  had to be $4$. Could anyone provide an example of such a tree?
2. Is there a bound on $\max(v_i)$? If yes, why?

If this is a well-known problem (especially on a tree), please provide me with some reference links cuz I can't find any. Thanks in advance.

Example of $\max(v_i)$ being $3$:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a tree which requires $\max(v_i) = 3$?

Comment: Isn't such an assignment just a coloring of the tree, which can be done with $2$ colors?

Comment: @AmitRajaraman  Yes, it can be done with 2 colors but you also need to minimize sum of $v_i$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Attached with an example.

Comment: Possible approach: Duplicate this tree, and connect the two vertices marked with 3 together.

Comment: @CalvinLin But after connection, you can just swap the $2$ and $3$ in one of the original trees?

Comment: @LearningMathematics Right, my bad. [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221475467_An_Introduction_to_Chromatic_Sums) seems to both introduce the concept and solve the question in polynomial time for trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $n$, there exists a tree $T_n$ such that every sum-minimizing assignment assigns $n$ to the root.
This is clear for $n=1$. Assume we know this to be true for all $k<n$. Build a tree starting with a root $v$ and adding $n-k+1$ copies of each $T_k$, $k<n$, as children. Then any assignment of some $k<n$ to $v$ implies that the copies of $T_k$ cannot have $k$ at their roots, hence cannot be optimal, hence have their sum at least $1$ too big. Then the sum for the whole tree is at least $(n-k+1)\cdot 1+(k-n)=1$ more than what we could obtain by assigning $n$ to $v$ and minimizing assignments to all subtrees.

Following this construction, the folowing trees have $1,2,3,4$ at their root (top node) in every minimizing assignment:
[image]